# jquery core not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

**Problem**
Scripts on some pages that use jquery are not activating.

**Scenario**
Finding that I couldn't get a script to work I put a very simple test script on a page in order to test that the jquery was functioning.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
      $(".testJavascript").addClass("hover_red");
});
</script>
<p class="testJavascript">This paragraph is to test Javascript</p>
```

This should add a red border but it will not function.

**Troubleshooting I've Tried**
I checked for the presence of the jquery core and it appears in the header of the page. Its enqueued and appears to be working correctly on some other pages, so I have no reason to suspect that its been corrupted.

I tried the following tests:

- Put the above script in the header template, just before the closing header tag
- Put the script in the body of  the page right above the test paragraph to which it relates
- Enqueued the script in case there was some sort of conflict that I wasn't anticipating. **This caused the page to stop loading - can't see why this would cause a problem.**. EDIT: After further testing I suspect this was caused by the $ vs jQuery nomenclature. Having changed it the enqueueing of this script no longer stops the page loading. however, the script still doesn't work.
- Finally since I'm a novice and I always suspect that I'm the cause of the problem I put the script and html snippet onto a page on my local MAMP server. It worked as expected. I think this exonerates my coding but maybe not.

I'm bemused as to what the cause of the problem might be.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to where to look for the possible source of the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a link to the wordpress site ? also do you get any errors I think you may have forgotten to include  jQuery ?

Comment: Need to see css and html, jQuery is just fine.

Comment: @mcgrailm   see valueDOTbusiness-navigationDOTcom. Home page is the problem. When you say "forgotten to include jquery" do you mean the jquery core? The header shows it loaded and when I click on the link it reveals what I assume to be the core. In addition jquery is used on other pages and some of those have jquery UI working, so I'm guessing that the core is loading correctly but maybe not? The fundamental problem is that on the home page you will see "...Feedback Form". That text should be in a UI dialog but its broken. The test Javascript para is only used to confirm that JQ works. THX

Comment: @AR  for html see valueDOTbusiness-navigationDOTcom.  The minor css for this test is at http://pastebin.com/b3qjzvau, main css for site includes theme from UI together with http://pastebin.com/XSaxGjGD. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering My Own Question**

The final solution to this problem was to enqueue the style sheet related to the test script.
I had referenced the css file by using a standard link in the header, added in the header template above the ending header tag. It appears that this wasn't working because when I enqueued the style file the script worked.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem could be that your testJavascript class has a border in css and appears before hover_red class. If that's the case, switch them, so hover_red  will come after testJavascript  in your css file (or within style tags)

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand you correctly you're suggesting that a rule for testJavascript is overriding the class hover_red. I don't have a rule for testJavascript, its only used as a selector, so I suspect that isn't the source of the problem. Just to make sure I changed the class to something really obscure and nothing changed.

Comment: Try looking in FF using web developer plugin - validate html. check firebug console, do 'inspect element' br right clicking, do CSS->View style information by clicking on that paragraph and its parents. It's hard to tell without seeing the page.

Comment: From FF: The script above from mcgrailm produces an "Error: $ is not a function" error message.

Comment: Validate html produces 8 errors but they all have to do with the "rel" attribute and a Keyword profile not defined. I assume this is not a major problem since some of the offending pieces of code are validations from search engines.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having jQuery conflict try it using [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $(".testJavascript").addClass("hover_red");
    });
</script>
```